Young adult novel series about timeships with Meso-American flair
I am trying to remember a book series I read 20-25 years ago in German (probably a translation, but could have been a German original).
The protagonists were school children who encounter a prince coming from an alien or off-shoot human civilization operating time ships. Time ships are basically small space ships with time travelling capabilities. The alien civilization is Meso-American flaired. They may have been Olmecs who left Earth, or have inspired their aesthetics.
There was a hostile faction also capable of time-travel, and everything may have started with the prince fleeing on the last functioning time ship of the good guys and crashing it or so. I'm quite certain there was more than one book, but I don't remember any plot details.
